# xamarin IllegalStateException activity has been destroyed on app closing

Tags: android, xamarin, xamarin.android, xamarin.forms

I get an IllegalStateException with "activity has been destroyed" when I close my app.

In my App.cs I declare a public static MasterPage:

```
protected override void OnStart()
    {
        // Handle when your app starts
        if (Device.OS == TargetPlatform.Android)
        {
            Device.BeginInvokeOnMainThread(() =>
            {
                masterdetail = new MasterPage();
                MainPage = masterdetail;
            });
        }
        else
        {
            masterdetail = new MasterPage();
            MainPage = masterdetail;
        }
    }
```

And in the MasterPage.cs I declare the Master and the DetilPage:

```
public partial class MasterPage : MasterDetailPage
{

    public MasterPage()
    {

        var IsLoggedIn = false;

        if (CrossSecureStorage.Current.HasKey("isLoggedIn"))
        {
            IsLoggedIn = string.Equals(CrossSecureStorage.Current.GetValue("isLoggedIn"), "true", System.StringComparison.CurrentCultureIgnoreCase);
        }

        Master = SetMasterContentPage();
        if (IsLoggedIn)
        {   
            Detail = new NavigationPage(new TaxonomyOverviewPage());
        }
        else {
            Detail = new NavigationPage(new LoginPage());
        }
    }

    ContentPage SetMasterContentPage()
    {
        var masterPage = new ContentPage { Title = "Test"};
        masterPage.Content = new StackLayout
        {
            Children = {
                new Label{Text="Label1"},
                new Label{Text="Label2"},
                new Label{Text="Label3"}
            }
        };

        return masterPage;
    }

    protected override void OnDisappearing()
    {
        base.OnDisappearing();
        GC.Collect();
    }
}
```

Comment: The `GC.Collect();` line probably causes this?

Comment: @GeraldVersluis No, unfortunately not. That was a try to fix the problem, but without success. I tried also with comment out `GC.Collect();` lines, but the exception is still there.

Comment: Is it when you close your app or you reopen it? See [this thread](https://forums.xamarin.com/discussion/72954/java-lang-illegalstateexception-activity-has-been-destroyed-on-pageradapter) on the Xamarin Forums with a similar problem

Comment: Its on app close, Ill try the solution from the Xamarin Forums thread. Thank you.

Comment: @GeraldVersluis The solution from the Forum don't fix the exception. I don't have a TabLayout.

Comment: Its a bug in Xamarin. https://bugzilla.xamarin.com/show_bug.cgi?id=46494

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Ok, that was a bug in Xamarin.Forms Version 2.3.3.175. To fix this bug install an earlier version of Xamarin.Forms. I get my app running with version 2.3.0.107.

The bug in version 2.3.3.175 should be fixed in version 2.3.4-pre1.

Comment: even on 2.3.4-pre1 the same happens to me

Comment: Maybe xamarin will not fix it in version 2.3.4-pre1 :( I am on version 2.3.2.127 and dont get this bug.

Comment: I have tested version 2.3.4-pre1 and the bug is gone.

Comment: After update of Android SDK 24 to 25 problem dissapeared.

Comment: Please use version="2.3.4.192-pre2"  - this issue fixed.